# “Please welcome Valued Associates: #958 - V2Blast […]”—Congratulations!

Tags: discussion

I just saw this link in the “Featured on Meta” bar, and thought it would be appropriate for us to also have a place to congratulate @V2Blast on the new job!

[Please welcome Valued Associates: #958 - V2Blast & #959 - SpencerG](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369260)

## Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you! I'm excited to join Stack Exchange, Inc. as an Associate Community Manager on the Curator Support Team :)

Comment: @V2Blast I understand this to mean we may now direct any and all complaints about everything to you.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: I assumed that was already part of my role as a mod here. :P